# Monitor my Azure function with Application insights

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to monitor my azure function to log performance insights and any errors occurred. As I am new to Azure, I've learned Azure Insights can make this done.

I used some settings to enable it.

**Windows:**

```
XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Java -> 1
ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION -> ~2
```

**Linux:**

```
ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION -> ~3
```

I am looking for any more details.

Comment: In what language is your function written? And what function version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to add the mentioned application settings in your azure function app as below:

[image]

Check the plan which you are using for Azure function. If it is linux consumption plan then make sure you add below key and its value in Application Settings in your function App.

```
APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_ENABLE_AGENT: true
```

If it is a python function app then check this [GIT](https://github.com/census-ecosystem/opencensus-python-extensions-azure) and [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-functions#distributed-tracing-for-python-function-apps) for [monitoring azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#:%7E:text=%20Monitor%20Azure%20Functions%20%201%20Application%20Insights,language%20of%20your%20function%20app%20project.%20More)